# Alteração de Upload

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com Upload de arquivos em PHP e no caso além de inserir arquivos no formulário pelo Upload, o usuário também podera excluir arquivos e incluir novos anexos no Upload porém estes dois casos não estão funcionando direito.

Segue abaixo o arquivo que faz a adm dos registros e a parte em PHP que irá fazer toda esta alteração.

Arquivo para a alteração do registro.

```
 <? 
#incluir arquivos de conexão e funções 
include "../UTILS/conexao.php";
//include_once "../UTILS/funcoes_usr.php";
#definir o char-set da página 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR"); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1252');    
set_time_limit(120); //Tempo limite de execução 
ERROR_REPORTING (E_ERROR); //Exibe somente erros fatais 

#Variáveis de Data e Hora   
$dataAt = date('d/m/Y');    
$horaAt = date('H:i:s');

$inserir = 0;   

$usuario = strtolower($_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]);
$usuario_1 = split('\\\\', $usuario);
$usuario = $usuario_1[1];

//variaveis para execução do SQL 
SQL(); 
global $sql; 

$idd = $_REQUEST["id"];//Varíavel para buscar o campo id do registro 

 //echo "O ID para alteração é o: ".$idd; 
//echo "<BR><BR>"; 

 #Cria a consulta inicial 
 $altEve = "SELECT [id],[mudanca],[tarefa]
,[descricao],[ambiente],[empresa],[reg_afet]
,[sist_afet],[hw_afet],[host_name],[serv_afet]
,[conclusao],[obs],[data_exec],[obs2],[upload]
 FROM [Passagem].[dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] WHERE ID= $idd"; 

 //echo $altPas;
//echo "<BR>";

 #realiza a busca pelos dados do registro 
 $result = $sql->execute($altEve); 
   if($tbl = $result) 
    { 
        $codigo = $tbl["id"];
        $codigo = $tbl["mudanca"];
        $codigo = $tbl["tarefa"];
        $codigo = $tbl["descricao"];
        $codigo = $tbl["ambiente"];
        $codigo = $tbl["empresa"];
        $codigo = $tbl["reg_afet"];
        $codigo = $tbl["sist_afet"];
        $codigo = $tbl["hw_afet"];
        $codigo = $tbl["host_name"];
        $codigo = $tbl["serv_afet"];
        $codigo = $tbl["conclusao"];
        $codigo = $tbl["obs"];
        $codigo = $tbl["obs2"];
        $codigo = $tbl["data_exec"];
        $codigo = $tbl["upload"];
        } 
else 
    { echo "Registro não localizado"; } 

#Inicia o tratamento dos registros      
while (!$result -> EOF) { 
    $id = $result->Fields['id']->Value; 
    $mudanca = $result->Fields['mudanca']->Value;   
    $tarefa = $result->Fields['tarefa']->Value;     
    $descricao = $result->Fields['descricao']->Value;   
    $ambiente = $result->Fields['ambiente']->Value;     
    $empresa = $result->Fields['empresa']->Value;   
    $reg_afet = $result->Fields['reg_afet']->Value;     
    $sist_afet = $result->Fields['sist_afet']->Value;   
    $hw_afet = $result->Fields['hw_afet']->Value;   
    $host_name = $result->Fields['host_name']->Value;   
    $serv_afet = $result->Fields['serv_afet']->Value;   
    $conclusao = $result->Fields['conclusao']->Value;   
    $obs = $result->Fields['obs']->Value;   
    $data_exec = $result->Fields['data_exec']->Value;   
    $obs2 = $result->Fields['obs2']->Value;     
    $upload = $result->Fields['upload']->Value;     


    $dataEx = substr($data_exec, 8,2)."/".substr($data_exec,5,2)."     /".substr($data_exec, 0,4);


    //echo "<BR>";
    $uploadExi = explode(' , ',$upload); 
     //foreach($uploadExi as $valores) 
        //{ 
            //echo $valores.'<BR>'; 
        //}


    #Move para o registro seguinte
    $result->MoveNext();

  }
 ?> 
 <html> 
    <head>
       <title>Eventos relevantes - CGR</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <meta name="authors" content="CGR - Governança"/>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Paginas.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../JS/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../JS/jQuery-Mask-Plugin-master/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body> 
<fieldset> 

        <?
            //echo "Data".$data_exec."<BR>"; 

            //echo "Data".$dataEx."<BR>"; 

            $dataExec = $dataEx;

            //echo "Data".$dataExec."<BR>";     

        ?>

        <form name="formEventos" method="POST" action="../UTILS/registra2.php">

        <!-- ID -----Hidden --> 
        <input type="hidden" name="eveId" value="<? echo $id; ?>">  


        <!--Mudança-->
        <p>
            <label for="idMudanca">Mudança:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveMudanca" id="idMudanca" class="medio" placeholder="Nº Mudança" value="<?=$mudanca;?>"/>  
        </p><br>

        <!--Tarefa-->   
        <p> 
            <label for="idTarefa">Tarefa:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
            <input type="text" name="eveTarefa" id="idTarefa" class="medio" placeholder="Nº Tarefa" value="<?=$tarefa;?>"/> 
        </p><br>

        <!--Descrição-->                
        <p> 
            <label for="idDescricao">Descrição:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveDescricao" id="idDescricao" class="medio" placeholder="Descrição do evento" required value="<?=$descricao?>" /> 
        </p><br>

        <!--Plataforma-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idAmbiente">Ambiente:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <select name="eveAmbiente" id="idAmbiente" class="medio"> 
                <option value="<?=$ambiente;?>"><?=$ambiente;?></option>
                <option value="">Selecione ...</option>
                <option value="Backbone">Backbone</option>
                <option value="Extranet">Extranet</option>
                <option value="Rede de acesso">Rede de Acesso</option>
                <option value="Lotéricos">Lotéricos</option>
                <option value="PAE">PAE</option>
                <option value="Rede 1">Rede 1</option>
                <option value="Rede 2">Rede 2 </option>
                <option value="Rede 3">Rede 3</option>
                <option value="Rede 4">Rede 4</option>
                <option value="Rede 5">Rede 5</option>
                <option value="Rede 6">Rede 6</option>
            </select>   
        </p><br>

        <!--Empresa-->              
        <p> 
            <label for="idEmpresa">Empresa:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveEmpresa" id="idEmpresa" class="medio" placeholder="Empresa" value="<?=$empresa;?>"/> 
        </p><br>

        <!--Região afetada-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idRegAfet">Região Afetada:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveRegAfet" id="idRegAfet" class="medio" placeholder="Região Afetada" value="<?=$reg_afet;?>"/> 
        </p><br>

        <!--Sistema afetado-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idSistAfet">Sistema Afetado:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                    
            <input type="text" name="eveSistAfet" id="idSistAfet" class="medio" placeholder="Sistema Afetado" value="<?=$sist_afet;?>"/>
        </p><br>

        <!--Hardware afetado-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idHardAfet">Hardware Afetado:</label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveHardAfet" id="idHardAfet" class="medio" placeholder="Hardware Afetado" value="<?=$hw_afet;?>"/>                 
        </p><br> 

        <!--Hostname-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idHostname">Hostname:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveHostname" id="idHostname" class="medio" placeholder="Hostname" value="<?=$host_name;?>"/>                   
        </p><br>

        <!--Serviço Afetado-->
        <p> 
            <label for="idServAfet">Serviço Afetado:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;    
            <input type="text" name="eveServAfet" id="idServAfet" class="medio" placeholder="Serviço Afetado" value="<?=$serv_afet;?>"/>                    
        </p><br>


        <p>
            <label for="idDataExec">Data de execução:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
            <input type="text" name="eveDataExec" id="idDataExec" value="<?=$dataExec; ?>" class="medio" />
            <!--<script type="text/javascript">$("#idDataExec").mask("00/00/0000");</script>-->
        </p><br>

        <p> 
            <label for="idConcluido">Concluído com Sucesso:</label>
            <select name="eveConcluido" id="idConcluido" class="medio">
                <option value="<?=$conclusao; ?>"><?=$conclusao; ?></option>
                <option value="">Selecione..</option>
                <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                <option value="Não">Não</option>
                <option value="Parcialmente">Parcialmente</option>
                <option value="Cancelada">Cancelada</option>
                <option value="Abortada">Abortada</option>
            </select>
        </p><br> 

        <p> 
            <label for="idObservacao">Observação</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <textarea name="eveObservacao" id="idObservacao" rows="4" cols="60"><?=$obs;?></textarea>
        </p><br> 

        <p> 
            <label for="idObservacao2">Observação 2:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <textarea name="eveObservacao2" id="idObservacao2" rows="4" cols="60"><?=$obs2;?></textarea>
        </p><br> 


        <p>

            <form method="post" action="../UTILS/registra2.php">
            <label>Anexo:</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidId" id="idHidId" value="<?=$id;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="eveArquivoAntigo" id="idArquivoAntigo" value="<? echo $upload; ?>" /> 
            <? 
                if($upload == '' || $upload == 'Sem arquivo anexo') { 
                    echo 'Não existem arquivos anexos para este registro'; 
                } else { 
                    foreach($uploadExi as $valores)   { 
                        echo '<a href="../UTILS/' . $valores . '" target="_blank" >'.$valores.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" name="hidValor" value="'.$valores.'"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="ExcluirAnexo" value="Excluir Anexo" class="botaoExc"><BR>
                        '; //disabled
                } 
            ?>


            <?  
            }       
            ?>
            </form>


        </p><br>

        <p> 
            <label for="idArquivo">Incluir novo anexo:</label>
            <input type="file" name="eveArquivo[]" id="idArquivo" disabled />
        </p><br>


        <p> 
            <input type="hidden" name="eveUsr" value="<?=$usuario; ?>" />
        </p>        


        <input type="submit" name="acao" value="Alterar" name="Alterar" class="botao"/>



        </form> 

        </fieldset>     
        </body>
        </html>
```

E agora a parte de gerencia de registros

```
  //Variáveis que serão usadas para tratar o upload de arquivo 
  if($_FILES['eveArquivo']['size'] == 0){
   $anexado = 'Sem arquivo anexo'; 
   } else {
   $total = count($_FILES['eveArquivo']['name']);

   for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {

   $diretorio = 'Uploads/';//diretório onde serão armazenados os arquivos
    //echo $diretorio."(dir)<BR>"; 

    $nome = basename($_FILES['eveArquivo']['name'][$i]);
    //echo $nome."(nome)<BR>";  


    $file = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/','',$nome); 
   //echo $file."(file)<BR>";

   $saida = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i','',$file);
   //echo $saida."(exit)<BR>";  

   $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['eveArquivo']['name'][$i])));//nome da extensao
    //echo $ext."(ext)<BR>";    

    $nomeFinal = $diretorio.$saida.'.'.$ext; 
    //echo $nomeFinal."<BR>"; 

   //$_SESSION['eveArquivo'] = $file;  

    $uploadOk = 1; 
    $fileType = array('doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx','odt', 'ods', 
    'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'msg', 'pdf', 'txt','htm', 'html', 'csv');//Extensões permitidas

    $maxsize = 1024 * 1024 * 9; //Tamanho máximo do arquivo 


       if($_FILES['eveArquivo']['size'][$i] > $maxsize) { 
       echo "
       <span> 
        Arquivo muito grande. Permitido somente arquivo de até 9,40Mb)  
       </span>  
       $uploadOk = 0; 
       } 

      //echo $_FILES['eveArquivo']['size'];
     //echo "<BR>";

      #Permite os formatos 
      $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['eveArquivo']['name'][$i])));
    //echo $extensao;
   //echo "<BR>";

   if(array_search($extensao, $fileType) === false) { 
   echo "
    <span> 
        Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: doc, docx,              xls,
        xlsx, odt, ods, jpeg, jpg, png, msg, pdf, txt, htm, html ou csv.    
    </span>
     "; 
     $uploadOk = 0; 
     } 



    //Checa se o Upload não foi carregado por um erro 
    if($uploadOk == 0) { 
    echo "Seu arquivo não pode ser carregado."; 
    echo "<BR>"; 
    } else { 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['eveArquivo']['tmp_name'][$i], $nomeFinal)) { 
        echo "<BR>";                
        echo "O arquivo ". basename($_FILES['eveArquivo']['name'][$i]). " foi carregado."; 
        echo "<BR>";

        } else { 
        echo "Ocorreu um erro ao carregar o arquivo."; 
        echo "<BR>";    
        } 
        }

       $fileExi[] = $nomeFinal; 
      //echo $fileExi." fileExi";
      //echo "<BR><BR>"; 


     $anexado = implode(' , ',$fileExi);    
     //echo $anexado." anexado";

     } } 


     //Cria a função para escolher a ação 
     function get_post_action($name) 
      { 
       $params = func_get_args(); 

        foreach($params as $name) { 
        if(isset($_POST[$name])) { 
            return $name; 
        }   

    }

} 

        /*Aqui vai a parte de Incluir que está OK ae tirei do código, deixei só o alterar e a exclusão de um arquivo de Upload */

         //Alterar registro
         case 'Alterar': 
        $id = $_REQUEST["eveId"]; //Campo hidden que será utilizado para atualização do registro 
        //$dataE = $_REQUEST["eveDataExec"];
    //echo $dataE; echo "<BR>";
    //$dataExec = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dataE));



     //Incluir novo anexo 
     if($_REQUEST["eveDataExec"] == '') 
        {  
            $dataExec == ''; } else 
        {   
            $dataExec = $_REQUEST["eveDataExec"];
            $dataExec = substr($dataExec, 6,4)."-".substr($dataExec, 3,2)."-".substr($dataExec, 0,2);
        }

        //Procedimento interno para qualquer tipo de alteração dos arquivos anexos 
        $anexoAntigo = "SELECT [upload] FROM [dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] WHERE [id] ='".$id."'"; //AnexoAntigo

        //Executa a consulta 
        $res = $sql->execute($anexoAntigo); 
        $aneOld = $res->Fields['upload']->Value; 

        echo $anexado."<BR>";   

        $newAnexo = $aneOld.' , '.$anexado; 
        echo $newAnexo."<BR>"; 

         $dataExec = $_REQUEST["eveDataExec"];
         $dataExec = substr($dataExec, 6,4)."-".substr($dataExec,   3,2)."-".substr($dataExec, 0,2);


          $updateEvento = "UPDATE [dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] SET"; 
         $updateEvento .= "[mudanca] =    '".$_REQUEST["eveMudanca"]."',";  
          $updateEvento .= "[tarefa] = '".$_REQUEST["eveTarefa"]."',";  
          $updateEvento .= "[descricao] = '".$_REQUEST["eveDescricao"]."',";    
          $updateEvento .= "[ambiente] = '".$_REQUEST["eveAmbiente"]."',";  
          $updateEvento .= "[empresa] = '".$_REQUEST["eveEmpresa"]."',";    
          $updateEvento .= "[reg_afet] = '".$_REQUEST["eveRegAfet"]."',";   
          $updateEvento .= "[sist_afet] = '".$_REQUEST["eveSistAfet"]."',";     
          $updateEvento .= "[hw_afet] = '".$_REQUEST["eveHardAfet"]."',";   
          $updateEvento .= "[host_name] = '".$_REQUEST["eveHostname"]."',";     
          $updateEvento .= "[serv_afet] = '".$_REQUEST["eveServAfet"]."',";     
          $updateEvento .= "[conclusao] = '".$_REQUEST["eveConcluido"]."',";    
          $updateEvento .= "[obs] = '".$_REQUEST["eveObservacao"]."',";     
          $updateEvento .= "[obs2] = '".$_REQUEST["eveObservacao2"]."',"; 
          $updateEvento .="[upload] ='".$newAnexo."',";     
          $updateEvento .= "[usr_alt] = '".$_REQUEST["eveUsr"]."',";
          $updateEvento .= "[data_exec] = '".$dataExec."'";
          $updateEvento .= " WHERE [id] = '".$id."'"; 

          echo $updateEvento; 
          echo "<BR>";
          $result = $sql->execute($updateEvento);

          echo "
          <p style='font-size: 15px; color: #000080;'>Registro alterado           com sucesso!!!!</p>
          <br><p><a href='../FILES/alterar_even_tst.php?id=$id'>Clique aqui para alterar o registro</a></p>
           <br>";   

           break;

        //Exclusão de Anexo 
          case 'ExcluirAnexo':  
            $idPag = $_REQUEST['eveId'];//Id da página
            $id = $_REQUEST['hidId']; //Busca campo ID na página 
            echo $id."<BR>";
            $excAnexo = $_REQUEST["hidValor"];
            echo $encAnexo."<BR>";
            //Efetua a consulta no banco 
            $consulta = "SELECT [upload] FROM [dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] REPLACE ('$encAnexo','$encAnexo','') WHERE [id]=$id";
            echo $consulta."<BR>";  
            //Executa a consulta
            //$result = $sql->execute($consulta); 
            //Exibe o resultado 
            echo "O arquivo $encAnexo foi excluído com sucesso<BR>"; 
            echo "<br><p><a href='../FILES/alterar_even_tst.php?id=$idPag'>Clique aqui para voltar a tela de alteração</a></p>";
        break;
```

Bom no caso não está funcionando a remoção de arquivos e também não está funcionando ao colocar um novo upload...

---

No caso no arquivo de alterar, eu tenho os dois botões para alterar e para excluir anexo... quando eu clico em alterar, todos os campos é realizado o Update menos no arquivo de upload ficando como Sem arquivo anexo.

Para o código de excluir o arquivo anexo usei um réplica, substituindo a parte com texto no SQL pra vazio, mas também não tá funcionando...ele reconhece tudo  como vazio.

Comment: Só para eu entender melhor sua questão, você está colocando toda a validação no server side?

Comment: Explique melhor o "não estão funcionando direito".

Comment: Quando quero colocar um novo Upload, ele sempre retorna como vazio não fazendo nem o upload do arquivo nem colocando a String do caminho no banco. E o remover, ele sempre tras a variável como vazio não removendo parte da String no banco.